# SELECT Statement with IF condition MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table , it has columns

```
menu_id , parent_id, controller , action , action_edit , action_view , 


select * from test where  
( action like 'my_action.php' or 
action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
action_view like '%my_action.php%'
) AND parent_id !=0 ORDER BY `controller` ASC
```

When `action` or `action_view` or `action_edit` is `home.php` -> i want to omit the `parent_id !=0` .

I tried using

`AND IF(action='home.php' OR action_view='home.php' OR action_edit='home.php',parent !=0,)` instead of `AND parent_id !=0` but it's giving me a token mismatch error

but not working , thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally i have a solution

```
select * from test where  
( action like 'my_action.php' or 
action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
action_view like '%my_action.php%'
) AND parent_id !=0 ORDER BY `controller` ASC
```

instead of `parent_id !=0` i used

and `IF(action='home.php' OR action_view='home.php' OR action_edit='home.php',parent=0,parent!=0)`

Now its working , thank you for your help guys :) . I posted my answer because i thought it will be a help for future users with the similar problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select *
from test
where  'home.php' not in (action, action_view, action_edit) or parent_id <> 0) and
       (action like 'my_action.php' or action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
        action_view like '%my_action.php%'
       )
```

EDIT:

`not in` is dangerous with `not in`.  Let's prevent problems using `coalesce()`:

```
select *
from test
where  'home.php' not in (coalesce(action, ''), coalesce(action_view, ''), coalesce(action_edit, '')) or parent_id <> 0) and
       (action like 'my_action.php' or action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
        action_view like '%my_action.php%'
       )
```

Comment: Hi your code worked :) , but the thing is the action , action_edit or action_view can be home.php , the thing i want is to omit parent_id <> 0  ,when the action is home.php because homep.hp 's parant_id is =0 , when i executed this query , when the action is home.php , the result is empty :/

Comment: Can those action variables be `NULL`?

Comment: action_view  and action_edit can be NULL, action can not be NULL

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this?

```
select * from test where  
(( action like 'my_action.php' or 
   action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
   action_view like '%my_action.php%'
 ) AND parent_id !=0)
OR 
( action='home.php' OR 
  action_view='home.php' OR 
  action_edit='home.php') 
ORDER BY `controller` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT A.* FROM test A)
                   JOIN (SELECT B.* FROM test B WHERE 
                         B.action like 'my_action.php'
                         OR B.action_edit like '%my_action.php%'
                         OR B.action_view like '%my_action.php%')
                   ON A.parent_id !=0)
ORDER BY `controller` ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

How about :

```
select * from test where  
(( action like 'my_action.php' or 
action_edit like '%my_action.php%' or 
action_view like '%my_action.php%'
)) AND (parent_id !=0)) 
ORDER BY `controller` ASC
```

Comment: parent_id !=0 line should be executed only when the action or action_edit or action_view is home.php